# Почему на отчеты sonarqube срабатывает Windows Defender?

Tags: sonarqube, defender

После свежего обновления сонаркуба (8.6) перестал выполняться анализ одного из проектов (.net, c#). Падает по отсутствию одного из файлов, генерируемых сонаркубом. Со странным сообщением в логе про вирус.

[image: Вывод сонара]

При этом в логе Windows defender есть запись, что это он удалил файл.

[image: Лог дефендера]

Что это, бага в сонаре 8.6, в дефендере или проблема с проектом?

https://yadi.sk/i/N7D_cI3YoGgTgA

https://yadi.sk/i/qOd2QgDCTYIfLw

Comment: В самом проекте при сканировании антивирусом проблем нет.

Comment: При отключении "онлайн защиты" сонаркуб отрабатывает нормально.

Comment: Вынес ссылки на изображения отдельно. В тегах не распознаются